# WebAPI Help Pages - Read Controller Attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using WebAPI Help pages project from nuget to document my ASP.Net WebAPI services.

I have several controllers that have the  [Authorize] attribute and several custom Attributes.

What I have not been able to achieve is to have the Attributes added to the documentation.

So if a Controller is marked as  [Authorize], then the documentation for the controller would say something like "This XYZ Controller requires Authorization"

So my question is how can I modify the WebAPI help code, to document the attributes on my Controllers.

Model level attributes are working with no issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the installed `XmlDocumentationProvider.cs` at `Areas\HelpPage\` for this. There modify the `GetDocumentation(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)` method. You can inspect any attributes that are decorated no the controller type `controllerDescriptor.ControllerType` and accordingly change the documentation.

When upgrading the `HelpPage` nuget package you might find doing the above inconvenient as you might want to override the contents with latest bits...so instead you can create a custom documentation provider inheriting from `XmlDocumentationProvider` and instead make a small modification to the installed `HelpPageConfig.c` file and mention to your custom provider.